# Qt - Compilation for Linux is not compilation for Android? Why?

Tags: android, c++, qt, compilation

Qt 5 has Android support: using Android SDK and NDK you can compile Qt application to work on Android too. Now what I don't understand. Qt was a cross platform long before Android has borne. Which meant that it was able to compile on Windows, Mac and Linux. But Android IS Linux isn't it? Why I need special Android tools like SDK and NDK to compile for Android. Why compilation for Linux in not compilation on Android?

Comment: Android is the underlying system but software is actually java based. Therefor you just have a nother target system. Targets are windows linux osx symbian android blackberry ...

Answer (score 5):

Android is not just an OS but a complete stack of mobile software.

This is because the structure of android *(in context of applications)* is very much different form that of linux. All the android apps run on an instance of ***Dalvik Virtual Machine(DVM)*** and are sanboxed from each other. So any App which requires to run on android has to be DVM compatible.

Android is based on a custom linux kernal, it also uses the same file strucure, but speaking of in terms of a platform the Apps running in android run on a completly different environment.

[image: Android structure]
<sub>(source: [cubrid.org](http://www.cubrid.org/files/attach/images/220547/480/224/typical-schematic-of-android_structure.png))</sub>

also there is an official source here [Android Low-Level System Architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/index.html)

I don't know much about about QT5 but I think this info might be useful.

Comment: This illustration of the framework is great! Could you show the reference?

Comment: @SMR Since Qt5 (5.2 i think to be exact) it is possible to write apps in QT and deploy them to Android and iOS - http://qt-project.org/qt5/qt52

Comment: @Losiowaty like I said I dont know much about QT and how it works. thanx for the link you provided. Please, if have a better answer then enlighten us. :)

Comment: @SMR from your answer I didn't understand why file that can be executed on Linux cannot be on Android. How they restricted that all executable should be only APK?

Comment: "like I said I dont know much about QT and how it works" If you don't then you shouldn't claim "I think QT is not compatible with the android framework". It's a true statement of your belief, but it doesn't belong in this answer. Your beliefs are somewhat out of scope here.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest answer is android is linux but linux is not android.

Because android expects an apk. Android applications have resources, permissions etc. they run on different runtime environments.So android has linux kernel but in the OS level, most of things are different.

Comment: If Android is Linux than what is valid for Linux the same should be valid for Android. But it seam it does not. From with we can conclude that Android in NOT Linux. Agree?

Comment: @Narek You can certainly run generic Linux applications on an Android machine. You just can't expect to be able to install them using the app store, nor can you expect them to interoperate with the Android framework. So you're in a way wrong: if you want to take over the screen of a device and do your own thing, you certainly can. But if you want to interoperate with the Android environment, you must use the Android development kit to compile the software you're going to use (here: the Qt library).

Comment: @KubaOber so the only problem is that I cannot use app store and its features? But I can do whatever I can on other Linux systems?

Comment: @Narek You sure can. From the user perspective it'll suck, but you can certainly do it. Good luck getting the display to work, as on every device it'll need to be done differently - there's no single "Linux graphics" or anything like that. Almost every system/chipset has its own kinks.

Comment: @KubaOber that's why wee need Android SDK and NDK. As my code will work one one device but on other one won't. But if I use SDK-NDK they solve cross platforming problem, aren't they? (Just to triple check :))

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the mainstream Linux kernel, with additional drivers for the specific device, and other additional functionality, such as enhanced power management or faster graphics support.

At low level, Android has a different lightweight C standard library the bionic LibC. Instead of X11 it uses video framebuffer device. Also only a subset of POSIX standard is implemented to make the OS lightweight on Android.

Android applications are run on Dalvik Virtual Machine. There are also many other differences which makes Android more unlike a regular Linux distribution. It can be said that Android only uses the Linux kernel and that's all.

Because of these major differences you should use the specific version of Qt for Android along the necessary SDK and NDK to be able to develop Qt Android applications.